# Getting the image from a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uiimage

I'm trying to get the image assigned to a button on click, so I can assign it to something else when the button is clicked.

I think I'm nearly there, I've managed to get the following info from the button

```
Sender info is: <UIImageView: 0x757d9b0; frame = (0 0; 100 100); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x757da10>> - image-name.png
```

As you can see, the image name is appended at the end of the log but I'm not sure how to get just that.

The code I've used to get this is:

```
sender.imageView
```

Thanks in advance for any help

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @zoul for leading me on the right path.
I ended up doing the following:

```
UIImage *image = [sender imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.newButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s an `imageForState:` method on `UIButton`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, using `[sender imageForState:UIControlStateNormal]` is outputting `<UIImage: 0x71bcc60>` however

Comment: Managed to sort it after a little experimentation from your answer so I've marked it correct thanks. See the edit above for explanation